# Show PDF file inside web browser with iText

Tags: java, pdf, browser, itext

I developed a report (without and independent of any db datasource) only with `iText`. I know that with `JasperReports` this is easy. But in my case I just storage the report in pdf file or I used acrobat for java beans to show the report to user. Now I need to change my implementation code to show this report in web browser instead to save in the file.

How I can do this?

Comment: web browsers usually have support for PDF files via add-ons, what's wrong with letting the user to choose which add-on to show PDF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need 2 thinks, first the browser plugin installed on the browser and second to set the content disposition header as inline in the respose, otherwise the browser will try to download it.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\"file.pdf\"");
```

I assume that you've already set the **Content Type to application/pdf** and know how to convert an iText document to a bytearray and transmit it to the user.

A word of caution: if people outside your organization will use this app, the might not have the pdf plugin installed, in which case, the browse **will** download the pdf instead of displaying the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

if the browser has the appropriate add-on installed, you can just drag and drop a pdf-file into the browser and it will show it.

Or if you have a site on which you want to present the pdf, you just put a link to it:

```
<a href="your.pdf">link to your pdf</a>
```

Or did you mean you want to generate html-output for your report instead of pdf?